# How to use local Sqlite database efficiency in Dart/Flutter

Tags: database, flutter, sqlite, dart, flutter-datatable

I'm a newbie in flutter and android application.
I have developed a quiz app.
It loading a Json data from Firebase and i want to save it to Sqlite(for query fast purpose).
My problem is Json data quite complicated, it have multi data array nested(refer Json data as bellow)

Since Sqlite doesn't allow nesting tables within tables, I not sure how to organize or convert the data to Sqlite most reasonable.
I am thinking of saving all my Json as a String, but I know it not a good idea.
Any have a better idea, very appreciate it

```
{
    "title": "TEST title",
    "des": null,
    "ver": 0,
    "partOne": [
        {
            "number": 1,
            "correctAns": 3,
            "question": "question 1 here?",
            "ansA": "answer A here",
            "ansB": "answer B here",
            "ansC": "answer C here",
            "ansD": "answer D here"
        },
        // about 100 question
        ...
    // about 100 part
    ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try `Hive` or `Objectbox`. Both of them are local DB that easy to use and also faster than `SQFLite`.

If you want to learn more about `Hives`, you can learn here

- https://pub.dev/packages/hive
- [Flutter x Hive tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8cZKm9s228)

If you want to learn more about `Objectbox`, you can learn here

- https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox
- [Flutter x Objectbox tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AxYbdriXKI8)

this is the database performance benchmark between `Hive`, `Objectbox`, and `SQFLite` (image source: [link](https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox))
[image]

I have try both `hive` and `objectbox`. Its recommended for you if you have a complex data and want to solve the storing problem.

Goodluck, hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, I tried Hive as Hamza recommended, it seem quite fitting with my project. I'll try objectbox another time. Thank for your sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Its better if you use `Hive`, its a local DB that will let you solve your complex data problem. Super easy and works much faster than `SQflite`

**Things you need:**

- https://pub.dev/packages/hive
- https://pub.dev/packages/hive_flutter
- https://pub.dev/packages/hive_generator

And of course some tutorial as well. So,

- [Flutter x Hive Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8cZKm9s228&t=278s&ab_channel=JohannesMilke)

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Hi Hamza, thank for your sharing, I'll try to do it.