# whether hive or sqflite good for handling large amount of data in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, hive, sqflite

i am trying to create a note keeping app using flutter. I am confused that whether i should use hive or sqflite. which is good for dealing with large amount of data.

Answer (score 4):

with hive, size of application will increase & also sqflite is boring. i think floor or drift are the best options that we have.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use hive because hive is simple to use and has good performance.
If you look at the following benchmarks :[link](https://pub.dev/packages/hive#benchmark), it can be seen that hive is superior to sqflite

And sometimes we are faced with complex data storage like this case: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70833531/android-sqlite-solution/70836650#70836650). Hive can solve the case more easily

Answer (score 3):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/hivedb/hive/issues/170) you should probably stick to sqflite. Most people say they kept the heavy load in sqflite.

So I gather from the responses there that for big amounts of Data, sqflite is more appropriate than Hive.

Having said that, there is [ObjectBox](https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox) which is built for scale and performance, and comes with its own pros and cons.